Most natural definition of a product of smooth manifolds with a smooth manifold structure.
In this question,I want to ask and clarify(for myself) some points regarding the definition of product manifolds,so that I can appreciate the definition better.
The definition of any product structure(in whatever Category) as many as I have seen,is basically a structure that will turn the projections into morphisms of that category.In case of differentiable structure,I think the same philosophy of product is behind the definition of product manifold.If I were to motivate the definition to a student,I would go on developing it as follows:
$1.$ We want to give $M\times N$ a manifold structure that would make $\pi_1:M\times N\to M$ and $\pi_2:M\times N\to N$ both as smooth maps between manifolds.Also we would like to have a reasonable size for that structure on $M\times N$.
$2.$ Since manifolds are generalizations of Euclidean spaces,and locally should look like a patch of a Euclidean space.So if we take a point $(p,q)\in M\times N$,then we should expect our product manifold definition to be such that a small neighborhood of $(p,q)$ looks like a patch of the product Euclidean spaces(of respective dimensions).So,while trying to define the product structure on $M\times N$,the most natural choice for a local chart at $(p,q)$ will be $U_\alpha\times V_\beta$ where $U_\alpha$ and $V_\beta$ are respectively local charts of $M$ containing $p$ and of $N$ containing $q$.
$3.$So till now it is indeed the most natural thing that we have planned.Also a natural choice for local coordinates on $U_\alpha\times V_\beta$ will be simply concatenating $\mathbf x_\alpha$ and $\mathbf y_\beta$,which are the local coordinates with respect to the charts $U_\alpha$ and $V_\beta$.So our local chart turns out to be $\{(U_\alpha\times V_\beta),\mathbf{x_\alpha}\times \mathbf{y_\beta}\}_{(\alpha,\beta)}$.
$4.$ Now it will turn out that the change of charts maps are smooth for the simple reason that differentiability can be checked componentwise.Also,we will be able to show,that the projection maps $\pi_i,i=1,2$ are smooth when $M\times N$ is endowed with this smooth structure.
My Queries

Is this a mathematically sound intuition to give to someone I will teach?

Is there any scope for further correction or improvement.If any,please correct me.Also I welcome any idea that I could add to mine,that would help one understand the definition better and to feel that it is the most natural one.

Can we generalize it for arbitrary products?



Looks good to me.

@Deane I just saw your stack exchange profile and I am quite impressed as I feel there are many things to learn from you.Is there some way we can be in touch with each other so that I can discuss and ask questions and expand my discussion community for a more fruitful learning!

I think it best that you continue to post your questions either here or on other public forums.
